# Preference category is clickable when using preference library along with a material components theme

Tags: android, android-theme, android-styles, preferencefragment, material-components-android

When running a new preference library [sample](https://github.com/googlesamples/android-preferences) and setting the app theme to the new material components theme(i.e Theme.MaterialComponents.Light.DarkActionBar) the preference category is clickable and has selectable background:

[image]

Seems like a bug, but wanted to verify first I'm not missing something.